# Recurrence relation with a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, recurrence-relations

> Let $ \mathbf{M} = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$ and $\mathbf{X}_{n} = \begin{bmatrix}x_n \\ y_n \end{bmatrix}$. Solve $\displaystyle \mathbf{X}_{n+1} =  \mathbf{MX}_n$ for $n \ge 0$ with the i.c. $x_0 =2, y_0 = 0$.

I'm not sure how to solve this. My idea is to write this as $\mathbf{X}_{n+k} =\mathbf{M}^k \mathbf{X}_n$ for $k \ge 0$. But it's not clear how I'd get the solution from that, after I've gone through the calculation?

Comment: You need to diagonalize $\mathbf M$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you diagonalize the matrix,

$$M=PDP^{-1}$$ and

$$M^n=PDP^{-1}PDP^{-1}\cdots PDP^{-1}=PD^nP^{-1}$$

so that the $n^{th }$ power of a diagonal matrix is the diagonal made of the $n^{th}$ powers.

Depending on the values of the Eigenvalues, the diagonal elements converge to zero or diverge to infinity (and $1$ remains and $-1$ alternates).

But in this exercise, all of this is useless as the initial conditions are null.

Comment: I got the initial condition wrong. Also I thought it was $M = P^{-1}DP$? Thanks. So after I find $M^kX_n $, I let $k=0$?

Comment: @Farthing: no, $X_n=M^nX_0$.

Comment: In general does $PDP^{-1} = P^{-1}DP$?

Comment: @Farthing: consider $Q=P^{-1}$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Take a good look at that initial condition. What is $\mathbf X_1$?

Comment: I'm sorry I typed the initial condition wrong.

Comment: @Farthing Well, then. Diagonalisation it is. Or you could try to _first_ solve the initial value problem $M_0=M, M_n=MM_{n-1}$. Whichever you think is easiest.

Answer (score 0):

Alt. hint (without matrix powers):   the recurrence relations can be written as:

$$
\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
x_{n+1}=2 x_n + y_n \\
y_{n+1}=x_n + 2y_n
\end{cases}
\end{align}
$$

Subtracting the two equalities gives $\,x_{n+1}-y_{n+1}=x_n-y_n\,$, which telescopes to:

$$x_n-y_n=x_{n-1}-y_{n-1}=\ldots=x_0-y_0=C$$

Thus $\,y_n=x_n-C\,$, and substituting back into the first relation gives the simple recurrence in $\,x_n\,$:

$$
x_{n+1}=2x_n+(x_n-C) \quad\iff\quad x_{n+1}=3x_n - C
$$